# jQuery I need to add an div over

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-table, event-handling

I have this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/fCeug/8/).

Now when the user clicks on the div with id `add` over any the first td element with id `1st`

The div should be: [image]

This might look as wage question so I added this image.
Now let be

> contentcontentcontent

to be the td

And the box to be the overhead div.

Now how do I add it using jQuery ?
[CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/fCeug/12/)
I tried to do something like this but this add the div comes to the next to it not over it.

Comment: over as in hiding the #1st? also: IDs can't start with numbers, and you can't add a div to a tr, only td and th

Comment: I just put the name randomly. And y cant we add div to tr ? :O

Comment: And if not possible td could also work

Comment: Sry, but in regards of formatting: Is the use of the rather large image "contentcontentcontent" really necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
$("#add").click(function() {
    $("#table").prepend("<div class='overhead'>This Is a div above another</div>")
});
```

Also try to avoid numeric values in  ID's.

Comment: Well this will add the div before the td but i want it above the tr

Comment: So: 
$("#add").click(function() {
    $("#1st").prepend("<div class='overhead'>This Is a div above another</div>")
});

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're putting a DIV inside of a Table...  I don't think that is what you mean to do?

What I think you are trying to do is PREPEND another table row (or possibly a DIV) into your table.  So on your jquery, you want to say something like:

```
$('#table').prepend('<tr id="before"><td>content</td></tr>');
```

This will add the new table row with the new content above the 1st table row already there.

Comment: Well this will add the div before the td but i want it above the tr